# FreeMarker: get results as DOM tree

Tags: freemarker

I want to use FreeMarker to process an XML template. However, instead of letting FreeMarker write the output to a Writer, I’d like to traverse the processed DOM tree. (Essentially, I want to fill a Protobuf3 structure from it.)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker is not imposing any kind of DOM-like structure on the template — unlike Thymeleaf.

So, it is not possible to automatically get a DOM, but the output has to be parsed into a DOM afterwards.